# Get a hash of old attribute values from rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to generically access the old attributes that have changed in a model - that is, I want to get a hash of the old attributes values. My code is interested in all attributes that have changed, which may be a different set each time it's run.

I know you can get an array of changed attribute names with

```
model.changed
```

and I know you can do

```
model.attribute_was
```

to get the old value of an attribute if you know the name, but I can't find a way to programatically combine the two or to otherwise get the set of old values

I'm using it to create news stories about objects, eg

> User 'Bob' changed x from a to b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attributes hash to generate this array:

```
old = model.changed.map{|attr| model.send("#{attr}_was".to_sym) }
```

Comment: Thanks Matzi, and for those reading who want to turn that into a hash of changed values:
`old = Hash[model.changed.zip].inject({}) {|h, (k,v)| h[k] = model.send("#{k}_was".to_sym); h }`